# Erro com vetor - erro de ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, lógica

Pessoal estou tentando resolver esse exercicio

> Desenvolver um programa para receber o nome de um aluno com suas
> respectivas 2 notas, em seguida calcular a média do aluno e apresentar
> ao final a média calculada e a situação de aprovação do aluno.
> (aprovado com média >= 6).
>
> - Utilizar o código para uma turma de 30 alunos.
> - Calcular e mostrar a média geral da turma
> - Mostrar a maior média da turma
> - Mostrar a menor média da turma

Já tentei

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] aluno;
    float nota1[], nota2[], media[], mediaTurma;
    aluno = new String[30];
    nota1 = new float[30];
    nota2 = new float[30];
    media = new float[30];
    mediaTurma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do Aluno: ");
        aluno[30] = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor da primeira nota: ");
        nota1[30] = teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor da segunda  nota: ");
        nota2[30] = teclado.nextFloat();
        media[30] = (nota1[30] + nota2[30] / 2);
        //mediaTurma += media[i];
        mediaTurma = i / 30;
        System.out.printf("A media do Aluno é %.2f\n", media[30]);

        if (media[30] >= 6) {
            System.out.println("Aluno aprovado Parabens!");
        } else {

            System.out.println("Reprovado, Estude mais!");
        }


    }

}
```

ao compilar recebo esse erro:

```
Digite o nome do Aluno: 
Bruno
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
    at ExercicioQuadro.main(ExercicioQuadro.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: vc fez um `for` mas está usando além do valor fixo (ex: `aluno[30]`) ainda está fora da faixa, o indice vai de 0-29, começa em zero, e no lugar do `[30]` em todas as variáveis deveria ser `[i]`

Comment: e esse calculo da média está errado, precisa ter a soma de todos os valores e depois dividir por 30, isso não pode ser feito dentro do `for`, pode somar dentro do `for` mas só vai ter o resultado final depois do `for`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays são indexados em zero (a primeira posição é `0`, a segunda é `1`, e assim por diante). Como você declarou seus arrays com tamanho 30, as posições deles vão de zero a 29, mas você está tentando acessar a posição 30 (como em `aluno[30]`, por exemplo). E como é uma posição que não existe, ocorre o erro de `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Como você está fazendo um `for` com o `i` variando de 0 a 29, basta fazer `aluno[i]`.

Se bem que `aluno` é um array que pode guardar os dados de vários alunos, então eu mudaria o nome para `alunos` (no plural, para deixar bem claro o que ele está guadando). Pode parecer besteira, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) (fiz o mesmo para os outros arrays).

E eu não sei se precisa de arrays para guardar a primeira e segunda notas, pois parece que você só precisa guardar as médias:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int qtdAlunos = 30; // quantidade de alunos
String[] alunos = new String[qtdAlunos];
float medias[] = new float[qtdAlunos];
float mediaTurma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < qtdAlunos; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite o nome do Aluno: ");
    alunos[i] = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor da primeira nota: ");
    float nota1 = Float.parseFloat(teclado.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Digite o valor da segunda  nota: ");
    float nota2 = Float.parseFloat(teclado.nextLine());
    medias[i] = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
    mediaTurma += medias[i];
    System.out.printf("A media do Aluno é %.2f\n", medias[i]);

    if (medias[i] >= 6) {
        System.out.println("Aluno aprovado Parabens!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Reprovado, Estude mais!");
    }
}
mediaTurma /= qtdAlunos;
System.out.println("A média da turma é " + mediaTurma);
```

Na verdade, nem sei se precisa de arrays - o exercício não deixa claro se é para guardar os dados, apenas pede para calcular as médias.

Quanto ao restante (mostrar a maior e menor média da turma), dá para fazer tudo no mesmo loop:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int qtdAlunos = 30; // quantidade de alunos
float mediaTurma = 0, maiorMedia = Float.MIN_VALUE, menorMedia = Float.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < qtdAlunos; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite o nome do Aluno: ");
    String nome = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor da primeira nota: ");
    float nota1 = Float.parseFloat(teclado.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Digite o valor da segunda nota: ");
    float nota2 = Float.parseFloat(teclado.nextLine());
    float media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
    mediaTurma += media;
    System.out.printf("A média do Aluno é %.2f\n", media);
    if (media > maiorMedia)
        maiorMedia = media;
    if (media < menorMedia)
        menorMedia = media;

    if (media >= 6) {
        System.out.printf("Aluno %s aprovado. Parabéns!\n", nome);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Aluno %s reprovado.\n", nome);
    }
}
mediaTurma /= qtdAlunos;
System.out.println("\nA média da turma é " + mediaTurma);
System.out.println("A maior média é " + maiorMedia);
System.out.println("A menor média é " + menorMedia);
```